# Swap touchpad buttons independently of the touchpad

Tags: touchpad, xmodmap, xinput

I use a Lenovo X250 with Debian.  I have a touchpad with 3 physical buttons on top.  Using xev I can see that these correspond to buttons 1, 2, and 3.  Additionally, the touchpad itself can be pressed.  Pressing it with one finger generates a button 1 event, pressing it with two fingers generates an event for button 3.

I would like to swap buttons 1 and 3 since I am left handed.  This can be done by calling:

```
 xmodmap -e "pointer = 1 2 3"
```

This has the desired effect for the physical buttons on top, however, it unfortunately also swaps the events generated by the touchpad click.  So, now a one fingered click generates an event for button 3 and a two fingered click generates an event for button 1.

Is there anyway to swap the physical buttons but leave the touchpad click intact?

Comment: What driver are you using for the touchpad (`/var/log/Xorg.log`)? If synaptics, you can configure the buttons generated by the touchpad click (`xorg.conf` or `xinput`, `man synaptics`).

Comment: Run `xinput list` to find the touchpad device name or ID then `xinput list-props "touchpad device name or ID"` to list properties that you can change with `xinput set-prop`. Setting one or more property may allow you to do what you want.

Comment: I am using synaptics.  I looked through the documentation.  It seems that TapButton1-3 and ClickFinger1-3 are the most likely candidates.  I've tried setting them via synclient, but they don't seem to change anything.  Do I need to restart something after setting them?

Comment: i think you can setup this at the desktop level (kde/gnome) on the setting panel if you are using one of those

Comment: I don't use kde or gnome. I use xmonad which has poor settings support.

Comment: An alternative: I use a mouse with which ever hand I feel like using. Because of this I don't swap the buttons. I have no problem with my left hand. There seems to be little or no bias between left and right buttons. I have trouble with some mice that are ergonomically right handed, but not with symmetrical mice. So my suggestion is: don't change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After more research, I discovered that the right way to do this is via xinput.

My Lenovo laptop has both a TrackPoint and Touchpad and their names tend to change over time depending on the driver I use.  It is important to ensure that you set the right device.  For me this is the TrackPoint.  It can be set to left handed operation using the following command:

```
xinput set-prop "$(xinput list --name-only | grep -i 'trackpoint')" "libinput Left Handed Enabled" 1
```

This flips button 1 and 3 but leaves the pad click on button 1.  This can be verified with the `xev` command.